# how to use std::pmr to reuse a buff

Tags: c++, c++17, std, c++pmr

I want to use `std::pmr`'s mechanism to build a object pool, but `monotonic_buffer_resource` can not reuse memory and other type memory resource can not be bound to a buff.
So how could I do, or just `std::pmr` can not be used as it.

And how does you use `std::pmr` in your program, please shared them. This is really important to me

Comment: "*other type memory resource can not be bound to a buff*" The pool resources can very much receive a "buff". They take a pointer to a memory resource that provides the allocations they use for their pool. That memory resource can be an object that just returns a pointer to that "buff".

Comment: There is no interface to transform a pointer to  synchronized_pool_resource or unsynchronized_pool_resource! 
Yes, I know we could  superpose these memory_resource, but monotonic_buffer_resource's feature won't be removed. 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory_resource

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user14542318: "*There is no interface to transform a pointer to synchronized_pool_resource or unsynchronized_pool_resource!*" You can make a `memory_resource` that just returns a pointer, and give that to those types. Those types cannot allocate memory themselves; they can only allocate memory though the given `memory_resource` (or a default one if the resource is `nullptr`).

Comment: Ok，you are right，I can do it like that. I think the std::pmr just give us a way to reduce the use of std::allocator, and a example monotonic_buffer_resource.  Really Thanks!